Expired permesso di soggiorno and with only ricevuta from Posta Italiane
Can we travel to Germany with an expired permesso? We only have the ricevuta of renewal from Poste Italiane, done with biometrics but the actual card is not ready yet.
I am a Filipino citizen, have been living in Italy with a work permit. That has expired and I now have a ricevuta.
I want to go to Germany for two days for a religious event.

No
Assuming you're not entitled to visa-free entry due to your nationality, you have to hold a valid residence permit to be able to travel to Germany. The "ricevuta" alone is not sufficient, as explained here by the German Diplomatic mission in Italy.
